# Formal Specification

Tags: c++, specifications

Is there any library/tool for formal specification in C++, such as [JML](http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/JML/) for Java, and [Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) in C#?

EDIT:

I am not looking for something more specific than, it's practical to use and adds some value/quality.

EDIT2:

I am not looking for UML tools, please see the examples I have provided.

Comment: Very good question - although I've only done formal spec for grad school assignments, I'd be interested to know if there's any tooling for it out there that's not strictly academic.

Comment: We use a wiki for our specifications.

Comment: A wiki works, however the problem I've experienced is that when several people work on the code the "wiki" and other forms of "specification" are less enforced with each iteration.

Comment: Are you interested in compile-time or runtime checks ?

Comment: As much compile-time as possible of course. However, it is somewhat limited what is possible with compile-time.

Comment: Hmm... it's become clear that when you said formal specification, you didn't necessarily mean Formal Specification. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_specification

Comment: "mathematical description of software or hardware that may be used to develop an implementation", which is exactly what the two examples I have provided do. I believe a better name would have been Design by Contract, although I didn't want to limit it to that if there are other tools.

Comment: Have you considered OCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Rational Rose UML software generates C++ code according to the complete UML model.

Never ever used it though, not really I mean. Just a brief look and only at UML functionalities.

Comment: Sounds something like Executable UML. However, I'm looking for a more formal way than assert to specify behavior of the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, never heard about Executable UML. Really interesting.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I meant was that UML is too formal, however the assert of C/C++ is not formal enough. I've worked with some UML based tools such as Bridgepoint, and they add more trouble than their worth. Function contracts and class invariants are what I'm mostly interested in.

Comment: No Pb, your mentionning Executable UML was pretty clear. I must dig this field. Very close to some of my needs. However not heard about something like this in C++. I'll follow your question if ever someone mention something in this trend.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Larch/C++ : [Larch/C++ Reference Manual](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~leavens/larchc++manual/lcpp_toc.html)

Answer (score 1):

frama-c - fascinating, jml inspired, i keep trying to use it but can't make the time - specific to c i believe. but should at least provide pointers to find c++ tools

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple tool to do UML without a fuss, [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/) is an open source (Windows only) project. I've used IBM Rational Rose and Microsoft Visio (with UML extension) and I have to say StarUML is just so nicely done.

I've never tried anything else than the class diagrams, and my experience is mainly for informal specifications and small projects. It also has some code generation features, but I've never tried them.